# Check for existence of specific data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select a DOM element with a specific attribute value. I'd like to avoid an each() loop, but all I've seen in jQuery is the ability to detect the existence of the data attribute, not its value. So, I want to accomplish something like this:

```
if ($('.item[data-index="' + indexVal + '" ]'){
  //if an .item with the data-index value of indexVal exists...
}
```

Comment: appending [0] will Boolean the jQuery hits, just like .length>0 or just .length if in an if() statment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
if ($('.item[data-index="' + indexVal + '" ]').length > 0){

}
```

Answer (score 8):

missing `)` and `$(selector)` should not be put in a if condition. it is always `true` even it does not select anything.

```
if ($('.item[data-index="' + indexVal + '" ]').length) {
```

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
if ($('.item[data-index="' + indexVal + '" ]')){
  //if an .item with the data-index value of indexVal exists...
}
```

or

```
if(jQuery('.item').attr('data-index') == indexVal){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$('.item[data-index]').length > 0

if you searching for specific value, you can insert the value in "" :

$('.item[data-index="123"]').length > 0

or

$('.item[data-index]').is('*')